# CSS sprite position

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a link, with which i want use plus, which will change color on hover.

[image: Plus]

But in the past hour i cant figure out how to do this trick with spites.

Here is a link, nothing special

```
<a href="detailed.html" class="plus">Find Out More!</a>
```

My css code

```
.block a.plus {
    background: url("images/plus.png") no-repeat 0% 40%;
    background-position: 10px , 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.block a.plus:hover{
    /*Just for example*/
    background-position: -15px -1px;
}
```

And also plus img [image]

Comment: what you want? if user click on plus so change color of text?

Comment: Yes, as you see, in the first screen is showing 2 pluses, i need only grey, on hover appears red.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 in future please read question fully - CSS sprite position. Where there is something about different images???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS sprites are often vertical arranged, since this will enable you to display only a specific line in your sprite file. In order to use the sprite technique on horizontal arranged images you have to create a second element with a non-transparent background:

```
<a href="detailed.html" class="plus">
    <span>Find Out More!</span>
</a>

.block a.plus {
    background: url("images/plus.png") no-repeat 0% 40%;
    background-position: 10px , 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 16px; /* actual width of one icon */
}
.block a.plus:hover{
    /*Just for example*/
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}   
.block a.plus span{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

If you don't want to use a second element you should rearrange your icons.

Comment: @NoNameZ: Did you try adding `display:inline-block` to `a.plus`?

Comment: No, if i do - all designing going wrong. I just used
background: url("images/plus.png") no-repeat 0% 50%;
and
padding-left: 5px; (to span). 

My general problem was in     padding-left: 16px; /* actual width of one icon */ as you commented... I somehow managed miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the :before selector.

```
<a href="detailed.html" class="plus">Find Out More!</a>

a.plus {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

a.plus:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: " ";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: red url("images/plus.png") 10px 0 no-repeat;
}
​
```

The color `red` is just for testing, you can leave that one out. `-10px 0` is the location of the image in the sprite (`x y`).